# Inapplicability of Gauss' mean value theorem in an integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

What is the value of $$\int_0^{2\pi}\ln|i+2e^{ix}|dx$$

At first glance I thought of applying Gauss mean value theorem, but this is not applicable here as $\ln|z|$ is not analytic at $0$, which belongs in the region $|z-i|<2$.

How one can approach this one? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean harmonic, not analytic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a beautiful (and theoretically very important) generalization of Gauss' mean value theorem, it is called the [Jensen's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula). Given that you know Gauss' mean value theorem you can look up the proof of Jensen in Chapter 5 of Stein-Shakarachi's Complex Analysis.

**Jensen's Formula**: Let $\Omega$ be an open set that contains the closure of a disc $D_R$ and suppose that $f$ is holomorphic in $Ω$, $f (0)\neq 0$, and $f$ vanishes
nowhere on the circle $C_R$ . If $z_1 , . . . , z_N$ denote the zeros of $f$ inside the
disc (counted with multiplicities), then $$\log|f(0)|=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \log\Bigg(\frac{|z_k|}{R}\Bigg)+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log|f(Re^{i\theta})|d\theta$$

You have to use Jensen here, because unfortunately the function $f(z)=z+i$ has a root in $|z|<2$, and $\log|.|$ of it won't satisfy the hypothesis of Gauss' mean value theorem unless we make some clever manipulations.

Now apply the above for $f(z)=z+i$, then we have that

$$\log|i|=\log|1/2|+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log|2e^{i\theta}+i|d\theta$$ which immediately gives $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log|2e^{i\theta}+i|d\theta=2\pi\log(2).$$

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but using $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ we have
$$|i+2\cos(x)+2i\sin(x)|=\sqrt{4\cos^2 x+(1+2\sin x)^2}=\sqrt{4\cos^2x+1+4\sin^2x+4\sin x}$$
so that
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(5+4\sin x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(4)dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\frac{5}{4}+\sin x\right)dx.$$
Hence
$$I=2\pi\log(2)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\frac{5}{4}+\sin x\right)dx=2\pi\log 2.$$
The only way I could show the integral to vanish was using the power series for $\log(1+z)$,
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\frac{5}{4}\left(1+\frac{4}{5}\sin x\right)\right)dx=2\pi\ln(5/4)+\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(1+\frac{4}{5}\sin x\right)dx=J.$$
Assuming we can switch integral and infinite sum, and  since $4/5|\sin x|<1$, then the integral becomes
$$-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\frac{4^k}{5^k}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^k xdx=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}\frac{4^{2k}}{5^{2k}}\frac{\pi  \cdot\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_{k-1}}{\Gamma (k+1)}=-2\pi\log(5/4),$$
hence $J=0$.

Comment: Yes, it is completely dependent upon the $5/4$. I don't think you have a solution yet.

Comment: The most fun part is that the above complex integration appeared while solving $\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(5+4\sin x)dx$. So what you've done here is merely a backward calculation what I've already done. I want a rigorous solution of the complex integral without its real counterparts (preferably by GMVT) as I mentioned above.

Comment: That would be a nice way to do it, if possible. Just a thought but since I have extracted the answer ($2\pi\log 2)$, maybe applying your complex analysis approach to the alternative integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(5/4+\sin x)dx$ might work (or a similar integral)

Comment: @Pixel what does this symbol mean $\pi({\frac{3}{2}})_{k-1}$

Comment: @S.SundaraNarasimhan sorry it's meant to be $\pi\cdot(\frac{3}{2})_{k-1}$ where $(x)_n$ is the Pochhammer symbol (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html)

Comment: @Pixel Thank you! It should have been obvious to me, but I thought it was some new special function!! :)

Comment: @S.SundaraNarasimhan you are welcome. PS I'd not heard of Jensen's formula before, nicely added to my mathematical tool box :-D